# Using VBA to scale excel graph X-axis?

Tags: vba, excel, date, graph

I'm using a macro to generate graphs from a table such that the x-axis is a time stamp(date, time) and the y-axis is for the data at that time. So far, there is no problem getting this to work but the result is a graph that has "blank space" before and after the data(roughly 5-10 minutes before and after on a 1-hour time-frame). I have space constraints and this cuts into them so I'd like to utilize the entire plot area. Can I eliminate the blank space by extending the data to end of the plot area somehow? Any help is appreciated.

Additionally the files I need to use are for different time frames and lengths of time(ie, different length of excel rows). Is there a way to only graph the rows with content instead of a "worst-case scenario" like using A2:A100000 because I know it will never be greater than 100,000 rows?

Comment: Your question is unfortunately *too broad* for the Stack Overflow Q&A format. Once you have a VBA function that *attempts* to solve the problem, and you're stuck with a *specific* problem, and research doesn't turn up anything, you'll have a valid question for this site. Good luck!

Comment: Could we get an image of the data where it's pointed what you don't want to be counted and the code that you're using for it?